# PowerShell wait for output from function or invoke-command

Tags: powershell

I have a script block/function that returns PSCustomObject followed by Write-Host.

I want to get the output first then print the write-host but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
function ReturnArrayList {
    param (
    [int] $number
    )
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$folderList = @()
    $folderObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name    = 'John'
                    number   = $number
       
    }       
    #Add the object to the array
    $folderList.Add($folderObject) | Out-Null      

    return $folderList
}

$sb = {
        param (
    [int] $number
    )
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$folderList = @()
    $folderObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name    = 'John'
                    number    = $number       
    }       
    #Add the object to the array
    $folderList.Add($folderObject) | Out-Null      

    return $folderList

}

ReturnArrayList -number 5

#Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList 5

Write-Host "This write host should come later"
```

Result:

```
This write host should come after

Name number
---- ------
John      5
```

Desired result:

```
Name number
---- ------
John      5

This write host should come after
```

How can I get the return result first and print the write-host message?
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force PowerShell to write the output from `ReturnArrayList` to the screen before reaching `Write-Host` by piping it to either one of the `Format-*` cmdlets or `Out-Default`:

```
$object = ReturnArrayList -number 5
$object |Out-Default

Write-Host "This write host should come later"
```

Result:

```
Name number
---- ------
John      5


This write host should come later
```

---

Beware that your `ReturnArrayList` function does not actually return an `ArrayList` - PowerShell will automatically enumerate the item(s) in `$folderlist`, and since it only contains one item, the result is just a single PSCustomObject, "unwrapped" from the ArrayList so to speak:

```
PS ~> $object = ReturnArrayList -number 5
PS ~> $object.GetType().Name
PSCustomObject
```

To preserve enumerable types as output from functions, you'll need to either use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`, or wrap the it in an array using the `,` operator:

```
function ReturnArrayList {
    param (
    [int] $number
    )
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$folderList = @()
    $folderObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name    = 'John'
                    number   = $number
       
    }       
    #Add the object to the array
    $folderList.Add($folderObject) | Out-Null      

    return ,$folderList
    # or
    Write-Output $folderList -NoEnumerate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is usually output to the pipeline, while `Write-Host` bypasses the pipeline and writes to the console directly.

Using `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host` will fix this issue. You can easily find more in-depth information on this topic, and when not to `Write-Host`.